# Genesis Child and Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, genesis-theme-framework

I'm working on Custom Post Type and Genesis Child Theme. My code is

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_testimonial' );

function register_cpt_testimonial() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Testimonials', 'testimonial' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'testimonial' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View Testimonial', 'testimonial' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search Testimonials', 'testimonial' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No testimonials found', 'testimonial' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No testimonials found in Trash', 'testimonial' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Testimonial:', 'testimonial' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Testimonials', 'testimonial' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,

        'supports' => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),

        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 10,

        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( 'testimonial', $args );
}
```

If I pasted the codes into function.php of Genesis Framework, worked for me. But when I used the codes into function.php of a Genesis Child, nothing was happened. Please help me to find out the mistake I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can't test this as a child theme of Genesis, but i just tested it on a child theme of Thematic and it worked fine.  there isn't anything in the code that should prevent it from running.  that said, i don't like registering post types as part of a theme... what if you change the theme down the line.... do you just want to lose (not *lose* since it will still be in the database, but won't display anymore).  i've read a few posts about moving the registration of taxonomies and types to a site mu-plugin

see
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users

basically you will create a my-custom-functions.php file and put it in /wp-content/mu-plugins

and drop this code into that file.  that you'll always have the tesimonial type regardless of what theme you are using.  i think it is good to keep themes focused on display and not adding important site-wide functionality.